# How to make a scatter plot in DM script?

Tags: plot, dm-script

I have 2 arrays, one contains the x coordinate and the other contains the y coordinates. I want to plot out those points in a figure according to those x and y coordinates, such as a scatter plot. Is it possible to make a 2D scatter plot in DM script? Can lineplot do it?

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately not.**

**DM does not provide any display for non-orthogonal data or sparse data.**

Depending on your X/Y arrays you *might* be able to work arround that issue. If your X-values can be represented as `X = offset + var * increment`, then you can fake a scatter-plot by creating an image of `(Xmax - offest)/increment` pixels and setting all to zero, excpet the values for your x/y pairs.

You *could* do that with a 2D image as well. 
Just note, that a regular 2D display will  have the 0/0 origin in the top-left. To get a more "regular" display, you could flip vertically (and adjust calibration).

The following script outlines what I mean. However, in general I would say that DM is not the suitable tool for this type of data.

[image]

[image]

```
image xVals := [5,1]:
{
   { 2.5, 9.75, 5, 10.25, 4 }
}

image yVals := [5,1]:
{
   { 4.25, 3, 8.75, 11, 4.25 }
}

number sampling = 0.25  // Small enough to fit your data to integer!
image xValSampled = trunc( xVals / sampling )
number sizeX = 10 + max(xValSampled) 

image scatterPlot := RealImage( "Scatter (1D)", 4, sizeX)
scatterPlot = 0
scatterPlot[ xValSampled, 0 ] = yVals
scatterPlot.ImageSetDimensionScale(0,sampling)
scatterPlot.ShowImage()


image yValSampled = trunc( yVals / sampling )
number sizeY = 10 + max(YValSampled)

image scatter := RealImage( "Scatter (2D)", 4, sizeX, sizeY )
scatter = 0
scatter.ImageSetDimensionScale(0,sampling)
scatter.ImageSetDimensionScale(1,sampling)
scatter[ xValSampled, yValSampled ] = 1
scatter.ShowImage()
scatter.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplaySetCaptionOn(1)

image scatterInverted := scatter.ImageClone()
scatterInverted.SetName("Scatter (2D) inv.")
FlipVertical(scatterInverted)
scatterInverted.ShowImage()
scatterInverted.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplaySetCaptionOn(1)
scatterInverted.ImageSetDimensionScale(1,-sampling)
scatterInverted.ImageSetDimensionOrigin(1,sizeY*sampling)
```

Comment: Hi BmyGuest, your codes are very helpful. But I have a question. When I reduce the value of sampling, e.g. sampling = 0.08, I cannot see any white points in the scatter plot. I cannot understand what cause this problem...

Comment: Check if the display limits of the image are set correctly. Likely the data is so sparse that auto-surveying the limits excludes the values. Then all appears black... Or is your final image so big that it is too big for the screen and therefore shown at zoom<<1 ? The just the display could skip the points. A good check is to sum the images. If it is not zero, you have points :-)

Comment: Hi BmyGuest, Yes, the sum of my image is not zero, indicating I have points there. I use imageDisplaySetContrastLimits to set it between 0 and 1, and I can see the points now! Thanks a lot.